# Calling a function from the layout/view file in Yii

Tags: yii

I am new to Yii framework and i need to define a function which is being called from /protected/views/layouts/main.php page. can i knw were to define it(Controller/model), so that i can get the corresponding action defined within the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what the function does and how visible you need it to be, you can do one of at least two things:

1. Extend the base CController class, define the function there, and then derive each of your controller classes from this new class. To invoke the function, you would run `$this->myFunction();`)
2. Put the function in a model, instantiate an object of that model in the controller action function, and then invoke it in the view by `$this->myModelObject->myFunction();`.