# calling controller's action in another controller, making widget

Tags: php, yii, widget, scope

I have a problem in Yii framework, I want to call a controller's action in the layout/main.php page which is belong to the siteController, I did this:

```
$a = UsersController::actionRequestAlert($s);
```

then I got this error:

```
Non-static method UsersController::actionRequestAlert() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

so how can I solve this problem?

---

ok,
now I want to create a widget, here is the steps I made:

- created folder 'widgets' in folder 'protected'.
- created folder 'views' in folder 'widgets'.
- added this in config/main.php : `'application.widgets.*'`
- this is the code of widgets/Alert.php :

  class AlertWidget extends CWidget
  {
      public $alert = null;

  ```
  private $_data = null;

  public function init()
  {
      $s = Yii::app()->session['userId'];
      $r = Requests::model()->findAll('idUser='.$s.' and confirm =0 and unconfirm=0 and cancel=0');
      $i=0;
      foreach($r as $x)
          $i++;
          if($i<=0)
              $alert=null;
          else
              $alert="(".$i.")";
      $this->_data = new CActiveDataProvider($alert);
  }

  public function run()
  {
      $this->render('alert', ['data' => $this->_data]);
  }
  ```

  }
- this is the code of widgets/views/alert.php:

  echo $data;
- this is the code to how I use the widget in a view:

  $this->widget('application.widgets.Alert');

finally I got these errors:

```
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class AlertWidget in C:\wamp\www\mediastore\protected\widgets\Alert.php on line 27
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766608/calling-a-function-from-the-layout-view-file-in-yii

Comment: Create a method in siteController that calls the userController method. And do not call it statically (means, make a Object using keyword 'new')

Comment: views dont call actions, actions render views !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048190/passing-values-between-controllers/19049682#19049682

Comment: @mondjunge by this way I need to call siteController in every controller used in the main layout !!

Comment: @MohammadMawed: Ok, than it is not a good Idea. Since I do not know Yii very good I am a bad help, but Sidux has a valid point there: "Views do not call actions!", maybe you are breaking with Yii's Concept of a MVC Framework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make widget in Yii](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270631/how-to-make-widget-in-yii)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About first question:
You must define method actionRequestAlert() as static

```
public static actionRequestAlert() {}
```