# how to make widget in Yii

Tags: php, yii, widget

I want to create a widget, here is the steps I made:

- created folder `widgets` in folder `protected`.
- created folder `views` in folder `widgets`.
- added this in `config/main.php` : `'application.widgets.*'`
- this is the code of `widgets/Alert.php`:

```
class AlertWidget extends CWidget
{
    public $alert = null;

    private $_data = null;

    public function init()
    {
        $s = Yii::app()->session['userId'];
        $r = Requests::model()->findAll('idUser='.$s.' and confirm =0 and unconfirm=0 and cancel=0');
        $i=0;
        foreach($r as $x)
            $i++;
            if($i<=0)
                $alert=null;
            else
                $alert="(".$i.")";
        $this->_data = new CActiveDataProvider($alert);
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->render('alert', ['data' => $this->_data]);
    }
}
```

- this is the code of `widgets/views/alert.php`:

```
echo $data;
```

- this is the code to how I use the widget in a view:

```
$this->widget('application.widgets.Alert');
```

finally I got these errors:

```
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class AlertWidget in C:\wamp\www\mediastore\protected\widgets\Alert.php on line 27
```

Comment: You should name files same as class names. Did you mean `class Alert extends CWidget`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're going to access the widget using `$this->widget('application.widgets.Alert');` then, the widget class name should be `Alert` (like: `public class Alert extends CWidget...`) and the filename should remain `Alert.php`